# Object Disappears in Camera View Even After Clipping Distance Adjusted

Tags: rendering, objects, 3d-view, camera, object-mode

I am having a hard time getting an object to show up in my scene.  I already checked the clipping distance and I have messed with the layers to make sure I can view all the layers.  Any ideas?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clip' you are editing is referring to the world.

[image]
[image]

**This does not influence the final rendering.**

[image]

What is affecting your scene is the clipping of the camera. This is where you should increase your camera to crawl further.

[image]

Comment: Glad to have helped!